# Search for and disable users that have not logged on for x days

Tags: powershell

I've tried to create a new powershell script that doesn't seem to be working for me. What I want it to do is to find all users in a specific Organizational Unit and then see if any of those users have not logged in for the last x number of days. After that I want each of those users to be disabled. I have not built the entire script yet, because I'm stuck at calculating whether or not a user has been logged in at all.

The script I have so far looks like this

```
    import-module ActiveDirectory

    $numdays = read-host 'provide the number of days user has not logged in'
    $OUN = read-host 'provide the Organizational Unit name'
    $nu = get-date -format dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss
    $logfile = ".\$nu.txt"
    $recent = @()
    $oud = @()

    $currentdate = [System.DateTime]::Now
    $currentdateUTC = $currentdate.ToUniversalTime()
    $lltstamplimit = $currentdateUTC.AddDays(- $numdays)
    $lltintlimit = $lltstamplimit.ToFileTime()

    $Search = "TOPLEVEL DOMAIN"

    $ou = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Ldapfilter '(name=*)' -searchbase $search -searchscope Onelevel | where { $_.name -like $OUN }).Distinguishedname
    $users = get-aduser -filter * -searchbase "$ou" -properties * | where { $_.enabled -like "True" } | select SamAccountName, LastLogonDate

    $convert = foreach ($i in $users.lastlogondate) { [datetime]::FromFileTime($i).ToString('g') }

    #$array = foreach ( $i in $users ) {
    #if ( $users.Lastlogondate -ge $lltintlimit ) { $recent += $i } else { $oud += $i}
```

As you might be able to guess the script fails at the convert part. Everything after is comment, I have not really done anything with that yet. Anyway I want to convert the output to a normal date system so I can calculate whether or not the lastlogondate is before or after the period I gave earlier.

Do you have any idea how I can fix this, or an alternative to this that might work as well?

Comment: Your problem was simply that `.LastLogonDate` already _is_ a `[System.DateTime]` instance, and you could have used it _directly_. (The property that contains the same point in time as a _file-time_ value is named `logonLastTimestamp`). I suggest you accept bob's answer, however.

Answer (score 2):

There are some limitations to filtering AD accounts using the LastLogonDate property, mainly that LastLogOnDate is not *always* updated across all DCs, Technet article explains in [more detail](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22461.understanding-the-ad-account-attributes-lastlogon-lastlogontimestamp-and-lastlogondate.aspx).

```
    $inActiveUsers = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan "90" -UsersOnly

    $inActiveUsers | foreach { Disable-ADAccount -Identity $_ }
```

The online help for the Search-ADAccount can be [found here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617247.aspx).

Comment: ++, but please note that `-TimeSpan 90` finds accounts that haven't logged on since the last 90 _ticks_ (_microseconds_)(!), not _days_ (sadly, the linked doc page contains the same error in one example).To specify 90 days, use `-TimeSpan "90"` (note the required double quotes) or `-TimeSpan 90:00:00`.